# How to get roles of a user not based on only user details in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a project which contains some task list are there. When a user logged in, the user get list of tasks for that user. Each tasks are collaborated so every user have a role in the task. And the role will be changed on each task. so when user click a task based on his roles the controls like button or anything will be displayed.

EDITED: I am saving roles in the database. I want to fetch roles of particular user on particular task when the task is selected from database. then want to show and hide controls according to users role on that particular task.

How to achieve this in Asp.net mvc 4 with Role Provider?

Comment: Are you basing their roles on Active Directory groups or are you defining your own roles in a database?

Comment: Seems to broad. Do some research and come back with specific question.